# What is mean that MySQL Server is thread-based not process-based?

Tags: mysql

I read a book about MySQL. In the section on threads, I saw this statement:

```
MySQL Server is not process-based but thread-based
```

Then it explains about foreground and background threads. I want to know what that means exactly.. please check my thinking..

My assumption:

- process-based: can run two or more same programs
- thread-based: can run two or more threads in one process (program)

MySQL Server can't run two or more - only one. Foreground or background threads can be multiple.

So MySQL Server is thread-based..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL can run only one process. but multiple threads can be created.
If the user requests a query from MySQL, the client thread is created.
This thread will return to the thread pool when your session ends.
If there is already enough threads in the thread pool, this thread will be lost.
This value follows the value of the **thread_cache_size** parameter.